# NTOP vs NFSEN, which one?

Tags: networking, cisco, ntop, netflow

I want to monitor Cisco's newflows.

Which one of these tools do you recommend?

Comment: May have a better luck on softwarecs.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @peterh This post is 4+ years old. It was recently edited because of the tag cleanup, and as such bumped to the front page.

Comment: @Reaces Thanks - but I found it in the close queue.

Comment: @peterh Looking up further what you might be linking to, I guess you ment [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) with a small typo. Apparently though so far they consider tool comparison [off-topic](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-a-fair-question). It's quite hard to find questions a home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both will do the job. NFSEN collects NetFlow flows using the nfdump tools, NTOP collects NetFlow and sFlow flows using nProbe, which means you can collect and process flows from Cisco, Juniper, Procurve, Extreme and a number of other devices. NFSENS is pretty much a dedicated NetFlow analyses tool and if all you're looking to do is look over flows then give it a go. NTOP is much more of a general network usage analyser with a NetFlow plugin. It'll give you all sort of network statistics and enable you to look at your flows, all from a single console. I'd recommend NTOP.

Comment: Hello Ossan, thank you for your reply. For what reasons do you recommend NTOP? I plan only to monitor cisco's netflows. My main goal is to gather statistics on which traffic protocols are being used in the network.

Comment: Hi Andre, I prefer NTOP because by default it produces report style views into the collected data. The reports are easy to interpret and I'm able to drill down to specific hosts to find out how much bandwidth they've utilised, how many connections they have open and which protocols they're using. You get everything NFSEN gives you and a little more.

Comment: `nProbe` isn't free i believe you need license for that. Its only support somewhere `2000` flow in free version, Please correct me if i am wrong